# Applying for a student visa after receiving a rejection for a visitor's visa in the UK

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, nigerian-citizens, student-visas

I applied in June for a UK visitor's visa to attend a conference. This was my first time applying for a visa to the UK so I asked for help from a family friend who runs an immigration consulting firm.

He gave me a list of requirements and asked how much I had in savings. The university would be offering me a stipend but he said I needed to show that I had my own money. I had about 4000 USD. He said this would not be enough and that he would send me 2 million naira (about 2000 USD). From reading conversations on this site, I now know this is called funds parking.
I didn't otherwise scrutinise the form. He was a family friend who was simply helping me out for free.

Shortly after this, I got accepted for a Ph.D. scholarship in the UK. I intended to attend the conference first, then return to my country to apply for the student visa. During this period, I started putting the application requirements for for for student visa application together. I wanted to do it myself this time, and I felt he dragged things out quite a bit. I used the visitor's visa application form as a guide and almost immediately, I began to notice some errors.

By the first week of August, the conference was coming to an end and my visitor's visa hadn't been approved. As a result of this and the mistakes I had noticed, I decided to withdraw my application.

I called UKVI and applied for the student visa in the second week. This week, I got a notification that my visitor's visa was rejected for the following reasons:

> You have applied to visit the United Kingdom for 24 days to attend a workshop. You say that you intend to spend £3,074.22 on your proposed visit to UK and University of *redacted* is contributing £3,074.22 towards the cost of your visit. I acknowledge that you have submitted a letter to demonstrate funding. However, when assessing this application, I have considered your own personal circumstances in Nigeria.
>
> You state that you are employed as a *redacted*. You also stated that you have a savings of £5,631.65. I acknowledge that you have submitted documents including a letter from your employer and bank statements in support of your application. However, the information you have provided does not demonstrate that you are in receipt of your stated income or additional income. I am not satisfied you have demonstrated your own personal circumstances or that they are as such that you can be relied upon to meet the requirements of entry clearance as a visitor.
>
> To demonstrate your financial circumstances you have submitted multiple bank statements in your name in US dollars. However, I note that there are
> several deposits/transfers in these accounts that do not represent your stated income, some of which are from unknown sources. In the absence of demonstrating the source of funds, I am not satisfied that this bank statement represents a true and accurate reflection of your current financial circumstances.
>
> In light of all of the above, I am not satisfied that you intend to leave the United
> Kingdom or that you are genuinely seeking entry as a visitor. Your application is
> therefore refused under paragraph V4.2 (a) and (c).

My biometrics appointment for my student visa is this week, and I think I ought to write a cover letter to explain and upload this to my application. But as I sat to write, I noticed that some of the figures in my application, such as what I earn from my office, were not correct. I don't know where the agent got the figures from, maybe he made a mistake. I wrote the cover letter for the application myself, so those ones match. I also don't know how to explain the parked funds.

Saying that I was careless and trusted someone who made a mistake doesn't sound like a very good excuse, but I do want to make it clear that I did not deliberately deceive them because that was not my intention.

**Do I need to address the previous refusal and how do I do so?** I was told that ordinarily, I'd need to prove that my circumstances have changed since the previous application, but my circumstances remain pretty much the same, minus the parked funds which I returned.

I also have no way of way of proving this because I got a full scholarship for PhD and will not be showing anything by way of Bank statements.

I tried to construct an explanation for the disparities and the only thing I can think of was that my friend made a mixup in the application, because what I told him I earned was not what he inputted into the form, and even I don't know why.

Does the fact that I have a full Ph.D. scholarship count for something at least? Or should I forget about this?

Comment: The good news is that you have not been outright accused of deception. In your next application focus on providing accurate and acceptable documentation. If you feel the need to mention the previous failed application, keep it short and simply say you made an error of judgement by asking an agent to organise it for you, and were poorly advised.

Comment: Thank you! I'm thankful that didn't happen. I don't want to submit a cover letter if it would be unnecessary and draw more attention to my application than advisable.

Comment: Would your advice then be for me to write the purpose of the cover letter, acknowledge the reason behind the earlier rejections and state that I was ill-advised without going into the finer details

Comment: You were ill-advised in your previous application and now your circumstances have changed. "I also don't know how to explain the parked funds": don't try. But didn't you say you already applied for a student visa?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I applied for the student visa a week and a day after withdrawing the visitor's visa application but before I got the notification that it had been successfully withdrawn. Two weeks later on Wednesday, I got both a notification that it had been refused and that the application had been withdrawn. But I haven't gone for biometrics yet and so I was hoping that I would use that time to upload any other supporting documents including the cover letter

Comment: **Never let this family friend help you with an immigration application again.** They made a serious mistake, and it was very likely that their advice was the main factor in your rejection. If you had a few thousand dollars in savings, and the university was paying your expenses then it is very likely that you application would have succeeded without his "help".